# ngRepeat argument into ngChange function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I'm trying to pass two variables from ngRepeat to a function but it seems that I'm missing something. Can someone explain what is it?

```
<tr  ng-repeat="user in users"><td>
<select
    ng-model="user.selection"
    ng-options="action.id as action.name for action in userActions"
    ng-change="actionChange(user.selection, user.id)"
    required>
</select></td></tr>
```

---

```
$scope.actionChange = function(selection,id) {
    $log.log(selection) // will display the selection
    $log.log(id) // is undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return `object` from `ng-options`

```
<select
    ng-model="user.selection"
    ng-options="action as action.name for action in userActions"
    ng-change="actionChange(user)"
    required>
</select>
```

You missed to write name to function & and add that function in scope.

```
$scope.actionChange =  function(user) {
    $log.log(user.name) // will display the selection
    $log.log(user.id) // is undefined
}
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/btrFFhe9q3wRwiXz4Acy)

Comment: Actually the options are working fine, I don't think that's the problem.
And about the function being out of $scope, that's not the case either. Just wanted to illustrate but I fixed the example.

Comment: Thank you, Pankaj! Passing the whole object did work. I've created a plunker for future reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/btrFFhe9q3wRwiXz4Acy